# Why does reading a file by creating a new thread take more time than not using a new thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, file, io, pthreads

So I am reading a while which is 3.5 GB long (actually that's half the size of the file. I am reading half of the file). What I originally had in mind was to split the 7GB while into two halves and read the halves in two separate threads and see if I could get a performance boost over reading the whole file in one go without any threads.

But, just reading half file in a newly created thread is taking way more than reading the whole file without any threads. Why is there such a difference?

Here's the code without any threads :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <filepath>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    struct stat info;
    if (stat(argv[1], &info) < 0) {
        perror("stat()");
        exit(1);
    }
    long size = info.st_size;

    long count = 0;
    FILE *fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        perror("fopen()");
        exit(1);
    }
    int ch = 0;
    while (count != size / 2) {
        ch = fgetc(fptr);
        count++;
    }
    printf("read bytes: %ld\n", count);
}
```

The above code takes 8-10 ms to complete on average.

Now, the same thing is being doing using pthreads,

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE *fptr1;
long size = 0;
long by = 0;

void *read_file(void *param) {
    long count = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    while (count != size / 2) {
        ch = fgetc(fptr1);
        count++;
    }
    by = count;
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        exit(1);
    }

    struct stat info;
    if (stat(argv[1], &info) < 0) {
        perror("stat()");
        exit(1);
    }

    size = info.st_size;

    pthread_t thread1;
    fptr1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &read_file, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("thread()");
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);

    printf("bytes: %ld\n", by);
}
```

This code, doing the exact same thing, takes on average 65-70 s.

Why does it take so much time in threaded case as compared to non-threaded version? Is there any point of reading a file in halves with two threads?

Also, I know `fread()` would be a better choice, completely agreed. I deliberately used `fgetc` because I didn't wanted to set up a buffer and what not. Since `fgetc()` is used in both versions, I guess the answer lies in threading and `fgetc()`.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Not related to your actual question, but "read the halves in two separate threads" sounds as if you expect to split the pure reading into threads might increase speed. Reading the file will not be faster, no matter how many threads wait for the same data. Only if you do complex calculations with the data, where CPU power is relevant, you might speed up things. Otherwise more threads will only add overhead. Your file system will not get faster by adding threads.

Comment: @Gerhardh There are (non-free) filesystems that do get faster, as they're much more complex and can be spread over multiple disks/devices.  For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPFS You can probably create a ZFS filesystem that could do it, but ZFS is a pig when it comes to performance so if you need speed you wouldn't be using it in the first place. Once you've done all that your applications/code needs to access the filesystem in specific ways to take advantage of those features.  But for the simple, single-disk filesystems that are most common, multiple threads will slow things down.

Comment: And the slowing down will be a **lot** worse if the storage is spinning disk.  Because file systems try to keep files contiguous on disk, reading with only one thread reduces disk seeking - the disk heads can stay over the disk tracks that contain the big chunks of the file.  Multiple read threads cause the disk heads to have to seek to different chunks of the file, and that takes a lot of time.  True random small-block reads from a spinning disk can easily reduce read throughput to the low KBs/sec range - 50 IO operations per second for consumer-grade SATA drives times 512 bytes...

Comment: The threaded cide has UB because it modifies a global variable with no synchronisation.

Comment: "because I didn't wanted to set up a buffer and what not." So bear the consequences (slowness) then. Fair deal?

Comment: @n.m. was gonna use fread() eventually, just thought to start with the simple fgetc() but was stumped. 
Also, unlike fgetc and fgetc_unlocked, fread and fread_unlocked give the same time in threaded version. Why so? Should fread_unlocked be faster since there is no synchronization? (I use 16KB buffer)

Comment: The "unlocked" functions are faster **if** you can use them.

Comment: The usual way to improve overall throughput with such an operation is to srquentially read the whole file with just one thread, passing large buffer pointers via a producer-consumer queue to thread/s that then process the data.  That allows data processing to overlap file reads.  How difficult that might be I cannot say - you do not detail how you need to process the data.

Comment: Oh... and 16K is much too small:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are multiple reasons for the threaded code to be slower:

- Using standard streams in a multi-threaded application is not recommended and has definite drawbacks: `fgetc()` is optimized for non threaded programs where it does not need to lock the `FILE` structure. In a multi-threaded application, to allow consistent concurrent access to `FILE` structures, all standard stream functions must use a lock to serialize access to the stream structure even if it is used in a single thread, because there is no way for the library to assert that.  This is very slow compared to the minimal task involved in reading a single byte from the buffer.

  If the stream is used in a single thread, you can use `fgetc_unlocked()` to bypass this overhead for `fgetc()` but there is no equivalent for more elaborate stream functions such as `fgets`. `fread` should not be a problem if reading large blocks at a time.
- Furthermore, the thread version *seems* to achieve the exact same task, but it uses global variables for `size` and `fptr1`, which has an impact on the generated code.  Furthermore, the function needs to reload the values from memory for each iteration because the compiler cannot assume that `fgetc()` does not change them.  This may prevent further optimisations in this version.

  Note that it is bad design to pass values to a thread via global variables, you should use allocate a structure and pass a pointer as the `param` argument.
- Note that if you create multiple threads for each to handle a separate part of the file, you will hit another problem: the threads will compete to read blocks from the file at different locations on the storage device, which may be very inefficient on some devices such as Hard Disks because these accesses will incur a head movement costing a typical 10ms latency per access.  Reading the file sequentially might be more efficient by a order of magnitude.  File system layout and cacheing, specific device characteristics and other factors may impact the performance and make it non reproducible.

For a quick test, try changing the `read_file` function to this:

```
void *read_file(void *param) {
    long local_size = size;
    FILE *local_fptr = fptr1;
    long count = 0;
    int ch;
    while (count != local_size / 2) {
        ch = fgetc_unlocked(local_fptr);
        count++;
    }
    by = count;
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The real explanation is that fgetc in threaded code equals suicide.

Comment: @n.m. yes, what is said is the real problem. When I used fgetc_unlock(), the time was same as the non-threaded version.

Comment: @n.m: indeed the stream lock is the problem. I updated the answer with an explanation.